# Dropzone.js not accepting .tiff images

Tags: dropzone.js

I am trying to upload .tiff images for dropzone but in dropzone queue .tiff format images are not getting saved. So any one has solution for it?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Not yet...but i have skipped this